# Accessing comments in Google Documents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am being unable to figure out how to access comments in Google documents using Google Apps Scripts. Looking at the API reference, I found only the [CommentSection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_commentsection) class, but that is marked deprecated. Looking for some help. Thanks.

Sanjay

Comment: Related: [Creating anchored comments programmatically in Google Docs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498275/creating-anchored-comments-programmatically-in-google-docs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not currently possible to access the document's comments using Google Apps Script. You can file a feature request for this on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Filed a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1618).

Comment: At this time it's possible to access the document's comments. See the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35494863/1595451) by [Nigini](http://stackoverflow.com/users/539223/nigini)

Answer (score 8):

Following the initial discussion in this post I've managed to get the comments in a document by using the [v2 of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
function retrieveComments(fileId) {
  var info = [];
  //These arguments are optional
  var callArguments = {'maxResults': 100, 'fields': 'items(commentId,content,context/value,fileId),nextPageToken'}
  var docComments, pageToken;
  do { //Get all the pages of comments in case the doc has more than 100
    callArguments['pageToken'] = pageToken;
    //This is where the magic happens!
    docComments = Drive.Comments.list(fileId,callArguments);
    //I've created a "getCommentsInfo" to organize the relevant info in an array
    info = info.concat(getCommentsInfo(docComments.items));
    pageToken = docComments.nextPageToken;
  } while(pageToken);

  return(info);
}
```

But, as the **Drive API** is an "Advance Service" you must add it both to:

1. *Script Project* - by using the "Resources > Advanced Google Service"
2. *Google Developers Console* - by:

   1. Making sure to select the right project in the top bar
   2. Enabling the "Drive API" for the Project

Comment: is there a way to get the actual content of google doc programmatically? thank you I posted a question about that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58359501/accessing-google-document-programmatically thank you