# How to I add anchor comments to a Google Doc file programatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have to add anchor comments to a google doc file using Google App Scripts, but I'm not able to do so. I tried using anchor while using the Document.Comment.Insert method but it does not work. Can anyone please help me by letting me know how to use the anchor functionality or is there any other ways to add anchor comments with help of a program?

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: Than what is the use of giving anchor while inserting comments.

Comment: If you create your own application to read drive files, your app can insert and read  those comments and put them accordingly in the file. Google doc's own comment system(the location data) is however proprietory. You can only append comments, if you know the encrypted location data(read existing comment's id/data).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating anchored comments programmatically in Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498275/creating-anchored-comments-programmatically-in-google-docs)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a comment using the [Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/create) instead. I haven't quite figured out the structure of an [Anchor](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-comments) for say a Google Sheet yet and am working on it myself.