# Can I automate a comment in order to assign a cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I understand that the setComment method is deprecated (and that it actually sets a note instead). Is there any other way to either set a comment, or assign a task using a note?

I'm trying to automatically assign a task to a user based on someone entering their email address into a cell. In other words, I click in the cell, enter an email address, and a comment is created that appends a '+' to the email and assigns it.

```
function onEdit() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var cell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
    var comments = cell.getDisplayValue();
    comments = '+' + comments +', please take care of this.' ;
    //Browser.msgBox(comments);
    cell.setComment(comments);
}
```

I feel like I'm close, but a note isn't really helping me here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating anchored comments programmatically in Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498275/creating-anchored-comments-programmatically-in-google-docs)

Comment: Looks like this feature has already been [requested](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756650), so I don't think it's possible. Correct me if I'm wrong.