# Location of a comment in its corresponding Google doc

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

Given a google doc retrieved through the Google docs API and its comments retrived with the Drive API,

How do you know where in the document a comment corresponds?

I've been inspecting all the fields and couldn't find a relation except the `quotedFileContent` that contains the commented text in the doc, but this would resolve ambiguously if that text is duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the location of a comment using Drive API.

As you can see in the official documentation, the [Comment resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments#resource-representations) has an `anchor` field that provides information on the [region of the document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-comments#define_a_region). Nevertheless, if you use the API to get information about a comment, you will see that the `anchor` field in the response is actually a string identifier composed of a `kix` prefix and a certain anchor ID as a suffix, which don't really give you an idea of where the comment is located.

The problem is not just about retrieving the locations to which a comment is anchored, but also about creating anchored comments in a desired location using the API, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498275/creating-anchored-comments-programmatically-in-google-docs).

Basically, as it is currently implemented, this `anchor` tool is meant for third-party integrations to use this API to specify their own custom anchor data.

There are several open cases in Issue Tracker related to this:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756056
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763384

Reference:

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-comments
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBU52nacbLw