# Google Doc comments - Update using Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I hope everyone is in good health. I am new to *AppScript* and love the concept of automating the Google Docs using it.

**What I tried;**
I recently got into a problem where I needed to update the text according to its comment in Google Docs using AppScript.
Here is the demo[image]  but I came to know that it was not possible by using AppScript, so I have to use *Google Drive API* and I tried it but I still didn't got successful. It did seem to be changed when I try `console.log(comments.items[i].context.value);` but everything was same in my Google Doc, nothing seem to be changed.

Here is my **code**;

```js
function listComments() {
  let comments = Drive.Comments.list(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId());

  if (comments.items && comments.items.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 1; i < comments.items.length; i++) {
      let comment = comments.items[i].content;
      let text = comments.items[i].context.value;
      comments.items[i].context.setValue(`[${text}](${comment})`);
      console.log(comments.items[i].context.value);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No comment found.');
  }
}
```

I can't find the documentation anywhere for updating the **Comment Context Value** in AppScript which will also reflect in my Google Doc.
I hope you will be able to address my problem. **Thanks** in Advance !

Comment: I am working with Google Docs not Google Spreadsheets

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking Drive API, I did not find any methods to update the comment's context.value properties. When updating comments, you need to use [**Comments.update()**](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments/update). However, this method only lets you modify/update the comment's content. If you are trying to replace a specific string in the Google Docs based on the comment's content, You need to update the document using [Document Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document) in Apps Script

---

When updating an existing comment you need to provide the following parameters:

**commentId** - The ID of the comment.

**fileId**  - The ID of the file.

> commentId is available in the Comments.list response

**Sample:**

```
 {
   "kind": "drive#comment",
   "commentId": "sampleCommentId",
   ....
   },
   "htmlContent": "Test Name",
   "content": "Test Name",
   "deleted": false,
   "status": "resolved",
   "context": {
    "type": "text/html",
    "value": "name"
   },
```

**Example:**

[image]

> content = "Test Name"
>
> context.value = "name"

If I will update this comment using [Comments.update()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments/update) with the following request body:

```
{
  "content": "My Name",
  "context": {
    "value": "name"
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I don't want to update comment 
The only wanted to update the text associated with it in the doc 
and as you mentioned to update Doc I would need to use Document Service but how would I came to know which text is associated with which comment

Comment: I could copy the context.value and search the doc file and replace the string with that text I want but their could be multiple same strings

Comment: No. I tried modifying only the context value but it did not reflect to the doc file. Based on the reference document update() will only update the content of the comment.

Comment: Regarding your initial concern in finding the context value location in the doc. Please refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58983822/location-of-a-comment-in-its-corresponding-google-doc

Comment: Yes, I also tried changing it, I thought it was because of some permission issues and you might get different results but it seems like context value does not get updated

Comment: that's right, it is not possible to update the context value

Comment: thanks for guiding me , Stay happy 
I think I have to use something other than comments to solve my problem

Comment: @abdulsamad you can combine what you have with `replaceText` instead, the catch is it replaces all occurrences of the text you want replaced.   `var docBody = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();` `docBody.replaceText(comment.context.value, comment.content); ` It works when you are sure the text you want substituted is occurring only once

Comment: Yes but as I mentioned earlier that there could be more than one occurrences

Comment: @abdulsamad, currently it is not possible to locate the comment in Google Docs. There are existing feature request regarding this. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58983822/location-of-a-comment-in-its-corresponding-google-doc)