# I am currently working in Apps Script, and I am needing to extract all comments from a certain sheet using Google Drive API. Is this possible?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

```
function listComments() {
  // setting the sheetId to the current sheet I am using
  var sheetId = '(mySpreadsheetId)'; 
  var arg = {
      pageSize: 100
  }
  Drive.Comments.list
  var comments = Drive.Comments.list(sheetId, pageSize=arg);
  var cList = [];
  // getting the active spreadsheet and current sheet to extract comments from
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheets()[10];
  Logger.log(comments)
  // Get list of comments
  if (comments.items && comments.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < comments.items.length; i++) {
      var comment = comments.items[i]; 
      // add comment and highlight to array's first element 
      cList.unshift([comment.content]);
    }
    // logging the sheet to check if I am using the correct sheet 
    Logger.log(spreadsheet.getName())
    Logger.log(spreadsheet.getSheetId())
    Logger.log(cList)
    // getting the spreadsheet to add the comments to 
    var commentsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheets()[11]
    Logger.log(commentsheet.getName())
    commentsheet.getRange("A1:A" + cList.length).setValues(cList);
  }
}
```

I am getting the lastest 20 comments, which is the default for the list function in the Comments api. I have been using the comments documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/list), but I have still been unsuccessful in getting the comments I need. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the pageToken to retrieve more pages

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630812/accessing-comments-in-google-documents/35494863#35494863

Comment: @Cooper Thanks I've been looking forever